# Create menus, sub menus and actions

Tags: menu, odoo

I have been looking for a way to create a menu item, and some sub-menus relative to that menu.

I want this to be the menu the users see when they log in, instead of the "Messaging" Menu.

Basically:
I want a menu on the top of the page, and it has to be the first one.
This menu needs to be the menu users see when they login.
On the left bar of OpenERP, i just want to add a few external links.
On the body of the page, i just want to write some welcoming text.

How do i do this? Do i need to create a new module? Or is it much simpler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new module [see here.](https://doc.openerp.com/contribute/05_developing_modules/)

And on this module, you must create an XML file to define new menu entries like this :

and if you need a sub-menu (under My Menu):

More explanations on [here](https://doc.openerp.com/contribute/05_developing_modules/#menus)

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/Help-1/question/How-to-create-menu-item-in-xml-file-in-OpenERP-7-9889    In this link, is that code useful? Where can i write that code?